# Not able to convert string into a char array

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string with spaces into an array of char without spaces.

Here is what I tried

```
string str;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str);
    int TempNumOne=str.size();
        char Filename[100];
        for (int a=0;a<=TempNumOne;a++)
                {
                    cout<<str[a]<<endl;
                    if(str[a]!=' ')
                        Filename[a]=str[a];
                }

        cout<<Filename;
```

The output looks like this

```
Enter a string: hello world
h
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d

hello
```

Only `hello` is getting stored. Why is this happening and how do I solve this?

Comment: Why the wacky indentation?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How does that strip spaces?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops I overlooked that requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because:

```
  if(str[a]!=' ')
          Filename[a]=str[a];
```

In "hello world", `str[4]` is `o`, and `str[6]` is `w`. The above code will: store the `o` into `Filename[4]` and the `w` into `Filename[6]`, instead of `Filename[5]`. A computer only does what you tell it to do, and now what you want it to do. Your logic did skip over the space, but all it did is that it didn't copy it into the corresponding position into the `Filename` buffer. This is not enough to accomplish the given task.

To do this correctly you need to maintain a separate index variable, call it `b`, for example, initialize it to 0, then:

```
 if(str[a]!=' ')
      Filename[b++]=str[a];
```

and don't forget to null-terminate the `Filename`, at the end.

Comment: That is correct, but it doesn't answer the original question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Filename` array is not initialized. That means that it may contain any values originally, including zeroes (which is probably what happens).

Now consider your algorithm - you start copying the data until the first space and you **skip** its location and continue with the second word. By skipping you leave the location corresponding to space location in `Filename` in its original state, i.e., uninitialized. If the original value there is 0, it corresponds to string terminator (`\0`). When you print the string, the parsing stops upon encountering `\0`, so you don't see the rest of the data printed.